# Jquery DOMNodeInserted not working in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cross-browser

I have a module to develop in which I have a parent table and for each row there is a child table both dynamically generated using JSON array via Ajax call using jQuery.

Now I need to fire an alert every time a child table with class "childtable" is inserted into the parent table row showing the id of the child table.

I tried to achieve this using jQuery DOMNodeInserted event and it works perfectly for me in IE but it doesn't work in Chrome.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87. The piece of code is as shown below.

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'table.childtable', function(e) {
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#'+$(this).attr('id'))) {

var tab='#'+$(this).attr('id');

 alert(tab);  //fire id as alert

 $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).DataTable({
        "bSort" : false,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "searching": false,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "paging": false,
        "columnDefs": [{
               "targets": [ 0 ],
               "visible": false
            }]

 });
  $( tab).find( "thead tr th" ).each( function( index1 ) {
    index1 += 1;
  $(tab).find("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index1 + ")").attr("data-title", $(this).text());
});


}


});
```

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` is a part of obsoleted [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Comment: i tried to read about mutation observers.but i m not able to achieve it.. can anybody help me with the code.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search i finally found an answer to my question. Thanks to Uzair Farooq.
The above thing can be achieved using the arrive.js which works on Mutation observers.
Click here to download the file.
[arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/)

Code:

```
$('body').arrive('table.childtable', function(){
   alert('#'+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Now my concern is i cannot use this code in old browsers.Bcoz mutations observers is not supported in old browsers.

So how can we find out whether deprecated mutation events is supported in browser or not using jquery?